# How Can I Run This Type of Xcode Debug test exactly on Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode-instruments

How can I Run This Type of Debug Tests On Instruments?

[PNG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1v67ynxdi5g11n/Xcode1.png?dl=0)

[PNG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/flvakk1fpxiley8/Xcode2.png?dl=0)

[PNG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/18j8gxlr9lk2usu/Xcode-Memory.png?dl=0)

What I mean is showing the "Stats" Results in a simple manner like on Xcode Pictures and the (Graph Display) also
but On Instruments, they have many tests on Instruments but they are too confusing I don't know how to read the stats as they give too much information, I need something more simple like the Xcode does on the Pictures, Why it's only available on Xcode? or did I miss something.
Why I just don't Run the project from Xcode? because I haven't got the Xcode Project for my Game, I just have the App Installed and the IPA file, so at the moment is more convenient to Run Instruments and Run the Game directly from there. Unless I can convert the Ipa to Xcode.
On Instruments they have Tests like example:
For Cpu Monitoring I found this Test but how do you interpret the Results is to much info on there.
Instruments Test CPU:
[PNG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g30atr10tgo7w5m/Instruments-Cpu.png?dl=0)

Comment: Update your question with the information you want Instruments to gather and display. That information will let someone tell you the right instruments to use to profile your game. One more thing. The third and fourth PNG links in your question are just duplicates of the first link. You can remove them from your question.

Comment: There are videos from WWDC sessions about Instruments on Apples developer website. I highly suggest to learn to use Instruments. Will make you a better dev.

Comment: Upps I don't know what happened with Pictures I apologise Thanks @ Mark Szymczyk for letting me know I update the PNGs now. I would like together the real stats for (CPU/FPS/MR) like on the Xcode Pictures but in a simple manner.

Comment: Thank you @ dasdom I will check them out between do you know why the Xcode Stats shows always low numbers like on (PNG 2) where it shows Cpu = 3% it should be much more done that, how does it compare those results?

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is not going to put the real stats in a simple manner for you like Xcode's debug gauges do. Using Instruments is going to require some work from you to gather the information. If your game is running fine on iOS devices, you may be better off not using Instruments. You generally use Instruments on a game when it's running slowly and you want to figure out why it's running slowly.

Should you decide to use Instruments, you should choose the Game Performance template from Instruments. It contains a whole bunch of instruments for measuring a game's performance. This template is available in Xcode 10. I'm not sure if it's available in earlier versions of Xcode and Instruments.

The problem for someone new to Instruments is that you're going to be flooded with data. Telling you how to interpret all that data is too much for a Stack Overflow answer. The following article shows you how to interpret the data from the Time Profiler instrument, which is one of the instruments in the Game Performance Template:

[Time Profiler Instrument](https://meandmark.com/blog/2016/02/time-profiler-instrument/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mark Szymczyk that was really helpful, I read the Tutorial many Times and will do more to understand it properly is a good starting Point thanks for that. To be honest, all I wanted is just to check the average stats (CPU/FPS/MR) of my Games, Example Run the Game for two minutes stop and get the Average Stats thats all I wanted nothing too complicated I didn need any advance debugging or hunt for my code just shows the Stats especially Im after the CPU stats as is the most important for me. But this simple task to archive is been like Mission Impossible if anyone has a solution

Comment: I checked the Game Performance Temple but I cannot see the game Cpu Average Usage for the current Game or App Runing do you have any Pictures that you can share showing it please?  Im ussing Xcode10. You mentioned that is better to use just Xcode to check the Statistics but Xcode dosnt show for me the real stats, it shows always (5 to 8) CPU% while a know the Game runs at (80 to 90)% Cpu it looks like is not working properly here is a demo Test if any one like to Try:  [Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybdqo0oxh2n0x8n/Zombies.zip?dl=0)

Comment: The Time Profiler instrument has a graph that shows the CPU usage during the run. Move the mouse cursor over the timeline above the graph to show a tool tip with the CPU usage. Instruments is not going to tell you the average CPU usage or average FPS.

Comment: @ Mark Szymczyk Thank you so much for your help:) would you mind to answer just a few more questions to make sure I understood properly? I really appreciate your help I put the questions on the PNG >>>> [Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn3ywyxq5wxmx65/CPU%20Questions.png?dl=0)  Thank you

Comment: I know the answer to only one of those questions. The total CPU usage is for the whole app. You may be better off asking a new question for the other two questions. With the new question,  add the screenshot to the question instead of providing links. Providing the screenshot in the question makes it easier for people reading the question.

Comment: Grate! That was the most  Important I need it to know the Total Cpu, Thank you @ Mark Szymczyk  I will do that and ask with a different question, take care man thanks a lot for your help and the tutorials